# Enoent rename error in NPM through docker

Tags: windows, docker, compiler-errors, nativescript, tns

I have a CI script to compile a nativescript mobile application that runs in a docker container.

When I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/.staging/proxy-lib-1731e398
npm ERR! dest /app/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/proxy-lib
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/.staging/proxy-lib-1731e398' -> '/app/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/proxy-lib'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /.npm/_logs/2020-02-20T10_15_12_334Z-debug.log
Could not update the project! Reason is: Command npm failed with exit code 254
```

From what I have been able to establish, this seems to be a NPM related issue, regarding permissions.

The strange thing is that the behaviour is only showing up when used through docker.

Compiling the application on my host works, but when I do so in a docker container in the same host, I get this error.

I have messed a lot with the permissions of the npm related folders, as I have witnessed a similar issue in the past, but now I don't seem to be able to get this to work.

Regarding docker and permissions, this is what I have set at the moment:

```
# fix for docker npm permissions
RUN mkdir -p /.npm
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /.npm

# fix for docker npm permissions
RUN mkdir -p /.config
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /.config

# fix for docker npm permissions
RUN mkdir -p /root/.npm
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /root/.npm

# fix for docker npm permissions
RUN mkdir -p /root/.config
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /root/.config

# needed for npm install and nativescript install
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/

# needed for nativescript install
RUN mkdir -p /.local
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /.local

# change owner of android sdk
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP $ANDROID_HOME

# change owner of android local settings folder
RUN mkdir -p /.android
RUN touch /.android/repositories.cfg
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /.android

# change owner of android local settings folder
RUN mkdir -p /.gradle
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /.gradle

# change owner of crashlytics local settings folder
RUN mkdir -p /.crashlytics
RUN chown -R $DOCKER_USER:$DOCKER_GROUP /.crashlytics
```

The docker user and group variables are 106 and 112 respectively.

NPM version is `6.13.4`

Node version is `v12.14.0`

** UPDATE **
Based on the comment left by David Maze, I am leaving here some additional information:

I am running a docker container using the below command, and only mapping the volume regarding the folder in the host that contains the source. One of the first step of the builds is deleting completely the node modules folder, as well as cleaning the cache.

Docker command:

`docker run -it -v my_host_folder:/app alfasoft/node-nativescript:0.17 bash`

After that, and inside the docker container, I am running all the steps I had in my Jenkinsfile (su to jenkins user, change to bash and then run all of this):

```
rm -rf node_modules
source /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use default
echo "Clearing NPM Cache"
npm cache clear --force
echo "Running NPM Install"
npm install
echo "Install angular devkit"
npm install --save --unsafe-perm @angular-devkit/build-angular
echo "Installing Nativescript"
npm install -g nativescript
echo "Installing TNS"
tns install
echo "TNS doctor"
tns doctor
echo "TNS platform remove android"
tns platform remove android
echo "TNS platform add android"
tns platform add android
echo "TNS update"
tns update
echo "build android"
tns build android --hmr --env.prod --clean --env.snapshot --env.uglify
```

Any hint on why this might be happening?

Comment: Things like this can happen if you have a volume for your `node_modules` directory, telling Docker that directory contains vital user data that must not be updated even if the underlying image changes.  Providing a [mcve] pointing out which line in the Dockerfile or at runtime causes that error would be helpful.

Comment: @DavidMaze more information added to try and clarify all of this